# are sas procedures source code available

Tags: sas

I understand SAS is proprietary software. I am wondering if the procedures that ships with it also ship without source code. For example, I see a PROC ANOVA in the user guide; is there anyway to look at the source code to see exactly how this procedure computes anovas?

There are some [threads](https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/How-to-retrieve-the-source-code-of-a-compiled-macro/td-p/320093) discussing viewing the source code compiled without a "secure" flag. Do the prepackaged procedures like ANOVA ship in this way (I don't have access to SAS to find out myself).

Comment: The secure flag is for SAS macros, which is different than licensed SAS Procedures.  The licensed SAS Procedures are available only in compiled form, only invokable from a SAS session as a PROC statement.

Comment: You can ask SAS tech support or how a specific measure is calculated but you will not get the source code. PROC ANOVA details section is a bit limited for sure http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=14.3&docsetTarget=statug_anova_details11.htm&locale=en

Comment: As noted by other commenters, SAS does not publish its source code. However, SPSS does document its algorithms in the [IBM SPSS Modeler 18.0 Algorithms Guide](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/modeler/18.0/en/AlgorithmsGuide.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find source code for SAS. R, on the other hand, is open-source, and so is Python. You could learn from those instead.

Comment: In other words, the standard procedures like for anovas and regressions are compiled with the "secure" flag? I understand there are open source alternatives. I'm not trying to learn anovas. I am trying to understand specifically how SAS computes something with more detail than the (admittedly helpful) user guide provides.

Comment: The secure flag applies, as far as I know, only to SAS macros (which are made of SAS code), not procedures (which are coded in C, most likely).

Comment: No, you can’t see the source code for SAS procedures. You can read the documentation. If you have a SAS license, you can call tech support. Typically the docs should suffice to explain how something is being calculated. If you have a specific question, pleas ask it.